# Button event isn't triggered (working w/ dynamically created classes)

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, datatables

I have three plus (+) buttons next to three separate tables (built with DataTables). Since the pluses were created in one location (with DT), they're assigned the same classes and clicking on any of them opens the same modals.

I dynamically added classes to each of the pluses in order to add specificity. I'm trying to trigger an onClick event for the first +, but for some reason it's not working.

Here's my question: Why isn't my onClick event triggered? Do I have to add more specificity? Is the problem with where the button was created? (see code below)

#### Button creation

```
loadDataTable(_payload, _grid, _def) {
...
var table = $(_grid).DataTable({
            data: _payload,
...
buttons: [
            {
              text:      '<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>',
              titleAttr: 'Add',
              className: 'dtAddClass btn' + _grid                
            },

// this creates:
// btn 1: class="btn btn-default dtAddClass btn.rolesgrid"
// btn 2: class="btn btn-default dtAddClass btn.srchgrid"
// btn 3: class="btn btn-default dtAddClass btn.additionalsrchgrid"
// this is exactly what I want
```

#### onClick event:

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn.rolesgrid", disp._newRole); // this does not open the modal

$(document).on("click", ".dtAddClass, .btn.rolesgrid", disp._newRole); // this triggers all of the pluses to open modals, which I don't want. I'm guessing it has to do with the .dtAddClass
```

#### Method:

```
_newRole(e) {
        dialog.dialog({ title: "Add New Search/Role Filled" });
        dialog.dialog("open");

        console.log('this is e: ' + e)
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: What sort of shenanigans is this: `class="...dtAddClass` ?!? What is this: `class="btn.srchgrid"`, `class="btn.rolesgrid"` or... `class="btn.additionalsrchgrid"`...?

Comment: Think you are missing a  space in `className` concatenation. If you have dots in the actual names that is just silly

Comment: @zer00ne it's just that `btn.srchgrid` and `btn.additionalsrchgrid` also contained `btn btn-default. I didn't want to write the whole thing out so I just shortened them with the ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MY ORIGINAL ANSWER (WRONG!)**

*left old answer in case someone thinks same thing as me to save them time*

*I didn't know you can have full stops in class names and I have been at this years, something new learned! However I would consider it a bad practice because of this issue.*

```
// this creates:
// btn 1: class="btn btn-default dtAddClass btn.rolesgrid"
// btn 2: class="...dtAddClass btn.srchgrid"
// btn 3: class="...dtAddClass btn.additionalsrchgrid"
// this is exactly what I want
```

Actually it isn't.

`btn.rolesgrid` is an invalid class, you cannot have a fullstop (period) in a class name.

The reason the second one opened them all is because you used a comma, you basically asked for 'if I click on `dtAddClass` OR `.btn.rolesgrid`

You need to strip the full stop from `_grid` and replace it with a space instead.

**CORRECT ANSWER**

As you have a fullstop you need to either escape it

`.btn\.rolesgrid` (older browsers may not support it)

or wrap it in square brackets

`[class~="a.b"]`

Neither are good ideas to be honest, would be better to strip the auto generated full stop and use a space instead.

Comment: Hey Graham, thanks for the info! I eliminated the . that was generated from `rolesgrid` and combined it with dtAddClass---the new `className` is now `.dtAddClass-rolesgrid` and I used it to open the modal. I'll be able to activate the other buttons (i.e. `.dtAddClass-srchgrid`) the same way.